# How to convert strings $foo$ to \(foo\) and $$bar$$ to \[bar\]

Tags: vim, latex

Everything is in the title. I have many LaTeX files written with the rather obsolete syntax `$foo$` and `$$bar$$` that I wish to convert respectively in `\\(foo\\)` and `\\[bar\\]`. I am using vim so I guess a regular expression will do but a script would also be perfectly fine. I have been looking around but without success.

Edit: following kirilloid's useful reply, I wish to mention to I would like to use this also in the case `foo` and `bar` are not only words, but expressions containing spaces (but no `$`s obviously).

Comment: following kirilloid useful reply, I wish to mention to I would like to use this also in the case foo and bar are not only words, but expressions containing spaces (but no $'s obviously).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
:%s/\V$$\v(\_.{-})\V$$/\\[\1\\]/g
:%s/\v\$([^$]+)\$/\\(\1\\)/g
```

Differences from @kirilloid answer are the following:

1. Using very magic (`\v`, disables need to escape most meta-characters) and very nomagic (everything but backslash have their literal meanings) modes for readability
2. Ability to cope with multi-line `$$` strings (`\_` adds newline to `.`, `\_.` is the only construct that really means *any character*, `.` does not include newline). `{-}` (`\{-}` in magic, nomagic and very nomagic modes) is the non-greedy variant of `*`.
3. There may be any character between these strings (`$`: any but newline), but it requires for you to ensure that there `$$` always starts outline formula and `$` always starts inline one. You may want to restrict the replace to the lines where this is true by either replacing `%` in front of command with `{first_line_number},{last_line_number}` or selecting them visually, typing `:` (`'<,'>` will appear at the start of command line) and proceeding to type `s/...` command without leading `:%`.

Comment: thanks, this is already very useful. I tried on a large file and the second formula seems to mess up things when a new line appears between two dollars (I mean inside an inline formula). What to do if I want to accept any character including a newline ?

Comment: @Niels Add `\_` in front of the collection. `\_` works for dot, collections and character classes (in last case `\_\x` can be reduced to `\_x`), adding newline to the list of matched items. Note: `\n` in collections works in the same way, thus `[^$\n]` will match anything, except dollar. *Anything*, including newline, that is why I suggest never use it: if you switch to perl-like regular expressions (present in most other languages) you will see that `[^$\n]` will match anything, except dollar and newline.

Comment: so to sum up :%s/\V$$\v(\_.{-})\V$$/\\[\1\\]/g then %s/\v\$([^$\n]+)\$/\\(\1\\)/g did exactly what I want (magic !). I don't quite understand what you mean by in front of the collection, could you be please be (even more) explicit ?

Answer (score 4):

Everything should be escaped: `$` is already a meta-character and should be escaped. `()+` should be escaped to work as they usually work in regexs.

```
:%s/\$\$\(\w\+\)\$\$/\\[\1\\]/g
:%s/\$\(\w\+\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: thanks, will this work also if there is more than one word between two $'s (respectively $$' ?)

Comment: no, cause \w is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, i.e. don't include space. In order to match spaces too, you'll need to use something like `\(\[a-zA-Z_\s\]\+\?\)`. I'm not sure, whether ungreedy local modifier is working in `vim`, though.